# MongoDB insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use 'POST' to create a new movie data with using MongoDB. but when I use 'postman' to post my data it kepts saying like this

{"message":"Operation `movies.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"}

I will post three javascript files please let me know about my problem.

First : index
Second : movie(module)
Third : routes

```
const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require('./models/movie');
//Fetch all movies
router.get("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find();
    res.send(movies) 
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
  }
})
// Add movie
router.post("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  const movie = new Movie({
    title: req.body.title,
    director: req.body.director,
    year: req.body.year
  });

  try {
    const newMovie = await movie.save();
    res.status(201).json({ newMovie });
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
})
module.exports = router;
//from here is Movie.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MovieSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 150},
    director: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 200},
    year: {type: Number, required: true}
  }
);
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
// from here is routes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require('./models/movie');
//Fetch all movies
router.get("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find();
    res.send(movies) 
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
  }
})
// Add movie
router.post("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  const movie = new Movie({
    title: req.body.title,
    director: req.body.director,
    year: req.body.year
  });
  try {
    const newMovie = await movie.save();
    res.status(201).json({ newMovie });
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
})
enter code here

module.exports = router;
```

I feel this is so hard to understand lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided code I don't see you that you are connecting to the database using `mongoose.connect` for example:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});`

[Link for the docs.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to refactor your code like this:

```
router.post("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let newMovie  = await Movie.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json(newMovie);
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
})
```